# What is the Intent to launch UI that displays all sms threads belonging to a conversation?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to  launch the android UI that displays all the sms threads belonging to one conversation (having the same thread_id). I tried different ways to do it, but without success:

1)

```
Intent i =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/" + thread_id));
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
startActivity(i);
```

I get the error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.test.intenttest2/android.test.intenttest2.IntentTest2Activity}:
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] dat=content://sms/conversations/3 }
```

2)

```
Intent i =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/" + thread_id));
i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
startActivity(i);
```

This one launchs the "create sms" UI which is not what I want.
Note that I have the thread_id with me,so basically I'm passing the thread_id and trying to get it to launch the UI for the list of threads belonging to that thread_id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I just got around this problem. The following code works to open an sms conversation using the thread_id. I got it from [android google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9bae700b9976ad23/b26739df3baead89?lnk=gst&q=sms%20thread#b26739df3baead89)

```
int thread_id = 11; //the thread_id of the conversation
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/" + thread_id));                
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this:

```
Intent i =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 

intent.setdata("content://sms/conversations/" + thread_id);

i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT); 
startActivity(i);
```

Thanks,

Shafali

Comment: Intent i =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);i.putExtra("address", "+1456666");i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");startActivity(i);